# Localize a whole sentense passing it a datetime

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I googled around but didn't find an answer - even if I guess it isn't tricky!

I'd like to localize a sentense that icludes date and time parameter. I want to pass it a complete datetime.

de_txt.yml

```
  de:
    article:
      will_be_published_at: 'Wartet auf Veröffentlichung am %a %e. %b %Y um %H:%M Uhr'
```

My function with *d* is out of the database, field type is *datetime*
(second line is the one of my problem)

```
  def icon_article_will_be_published_at(d)
    alt = t('article.will_be_published_at', d)
    image_tag("#{root_url}images/famfamfam/icons/date_next.png", :title => alt, :alt => alt, :class => "icon")
  end
```

more about d

```
d.inspect # => Sat, 03 Dec 2011 14:07:00 CET +01:00
```

I can't figure it out and would appreciate help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this, you will need the `I18n#l` method, not the translate method.
It's a bit tricky, because you need a separate time format in the translations file (de.yml). This is one way to do it (adjust as necessary):

In config/locales/de.yml:

```
de:
  time:
    formats:
      article_published_at: 'Wartet auf Veröffentlichung am %a %e. %b %Y um %H:%M Uhr'
```

Testing it in the console:

```
I18n.locale = :de

I18n.l Time.now, :format => :article_published_at
```

Answer (score 0):

I would propose the following:

- Split what you want to do in 2 steps:
- Define a special format `:um` as described in the [Rails Guide to I18n](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#adding-date-time-formats)

  ```
  de:
    article:
      will_be_published_at: 'Wartet auf Veröffentlichung am %datetime'
    time:
      formats:
        um: "%a %e. %b %Y um %H:%M Uhr"
  ```
- Call it then in the following snippet:

  ```
  time = l(d, :format => :um)
  alt = t('article.will_be_published_at', :datetime => time)
  ```

I could not test it, but it should work.